# Setting App Bundle as Referrer in React Native WebView for Local HTML & Passing Referrer in JavaScript Server Calls

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project where I'm using the WebView component to load a local HTML file within my mobile app. I need to set the app bundle identifier as the **referrer** when loading this **local HTML file and subsequently pass this referrer information** in JavaScript server calls made from within this WebView.

My objectives are as follows:

1. Load a local HTML file within a React Native WebView.
2. Set the referrer of this WebView to be the app bundle identifier.
3. In the JavaScript code inside this HTML file, perform server calls
   and include the app bundle identifier as a referrer parameter in
   these calls.
4. I'm facing challenges understanding how to set the app bundle
   identifier as a referrer specifically within the context of **React
   Native's WebView component and then how to access this referrer
   information within the JavaScript code for server calls**.

Any insights, code examples, or guidance on accomplishing this within React Native's WebView would be immensely helpful.